# Pass variable into function during list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a string `text` and I want to Lemmatize each word in it and put it back together as a string.  I am currently doing trying to do it this way:

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
text = ' '.join[lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in text.split()]
```

but I am getting the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think I'm not allowed to pass `word` into a function inside a list comprehension.  I have two questions:

1) Why is this not allowed?

2) How can I do this with another method?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `text.split(' ')` ?

Comment: @Sudipta: The default for `split` is to split on whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you forgot parentheses.  Either use a list comprehension and pass it to `join`:

```
text = ' '.join([lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in text.split()])
```

or just use a generator comprehension:

```
text = ' '.join(lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in text.split())
```

Comment: The later should be preferred.